# some questions in the book of Introduction to real analysis.

Tags: analysis

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEiKo.jpg

> The following statements are equivalent: (a) $S$ is a countable set. (b) There exists a surjection of $\mathbb{N}$ onto $S$. (c) There exists an injection of $S$ into $\mathbb{N}$
>
> *Proof $(a)\implies(b)$*: If $S$ is finite, there exists a bijection $h$ of some set $\mathbb{N}_n$ on $S$ and we define $H$ on $\mathbb{N}$ by
>
> $$
> H(k) = \begin{cases}
>             h(k) & \quad for\quad k = 1,...,n,  \\
>             h(n) & \quad for\quad k > n
>         \end{cases}
> $$

My question is: What does this bijection $h$ mean? And what is this $H$ defined on $\mathbb{N}$? How could a set $H$ be a surjection of two different sets?
I'm super confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this means is that we make a bijection $h$ from a subset of numbers, $\mathbb{N}_n$ corresponding to the finite set $S$ of $n$ elements which consists of mapping the numbers from $1$ to $n$ to the $n$ elements of $S$. Then the remaining numbers above $n$, $k>n$, are mapped onto the $n$th element. That part is not a bijection, it's just mapping the remaining elements onto somewhere or another.

The final choice is just an arbitrary one, we could map the remaining elements onto the first or second or whatever element of $S$ instead of the $n$th.

Comment: So here the H is just a function on N, just like the h is the function of Nn to S. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. $H$ is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $S$.